# Method call after invalid C-style cast works

Tags: c++, c++11, dynamic-cast, static-cast

So I'm trying to learn a bit more about the differences between ***C-style-casts***, ***static_cast***, ***dynamic_cast*** and I decided to try this example which should reflect the differences between ***C-style-casts*** and ***static_cast*** pretty good.

```
class B
{
public:
    void hi() { cout << "hello" << endl; }
};

class D: public B {};

class A {};

int main()
{
    A* a = new A();
    B* b = (B*)a;
    b->hi();
}
```

Well this code snippet should reflect that the ***C-style-cast*** goes very wrong and the bad cast is not detected at all. Partially it happens that way. The bad cast is not detected, but I was surprised when the program, instead of crashing at `b->hi();`, it printed on the screen the word "hello".

Now, why is this happening ? What object was used to call such a method, when there's no B object instantiated ? I'm using g++ to compile.

Comment: Casting to an unrelated type like this (what is effectively `reinterpret_cast` in C++) is undefined behavior. This means the implementation can do whatever it wants.

Comment: HINT: even a broken clock shows the right time twice a day.

Comment: A c style cast is just like the programmer telling the compiler 'trust me this is B object'. The compiler has no choice but to acquiesce. What happens when it runs is not defined. This is exactly why c style casts are so dangerous.

Comment: @Yuushi the cast itself merely has an unspecified result. It's the dereference (with `operator->`  in this case) that has UB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others said it is undefined behaviour.

Why it is working though? It is probably because the function call is linked statically, during compile-time (it's not virtual function). The function `B::hi()` exists so it is called. Try to add variable to `class B` and use it in function `hi()`. Then you will see problem (trash value) on the screen:

```
class B
{
public:
    void hi() { cout << "hello, my value is " << x << endl; }

private:
    int x = 5;
};
```

Otherwise you could make function `hi()` virtual. Then function is linked dynamically, at runtime and program crashes immediately:

```
class B
{
public:
    virtual void hi() { cout << "hello" << endl; }
};
```

Comment: Note that the standard does not guarantee that either of your suggestions must result in a crash.

Comment: @user2079303 That is true. It may happen that my computer will start mission to Mars after such call or will begin Terminator: Genisys. But if he is using gcc then it is probable that results will be exactly like mine: some strange value in first and crash in second example.

Answer (score 1):

> Now, why is this happening ?

Because it can happen. Anything can happen. The behaviour is *undefined*.

The fact that something unexpected happened demonstrates well why UB is so dangerous. If it always caused a crash, then it would be far easier to deal with.

> What object was used to call such a method

Most likely, the compiler blindly trusts you, and assumes that `b` does point to an object of type `B` (which it doesn't). It probably would use the pointed memory as if the assumption was true. The member function didn't access any of the memory that belongs to the object, and the behaviour happened to be the same as if there had been an object of correct type.

Being undefined, the behaviour could be completely different. If you try to run the program again, the standard doesn't guarantee that demons won't fly out of your nose.

Answer (score 1):

This only works because of the implementation of the `hi()` method itself, and the peculiar part of the C++ spec called *undefined behaviour*.

Casting using a C-style cast to an incompatible pointer type is undefined behaviour - literally anything at all could happen.

In this case, the compiler has obviously decided to just trust you, and has decided to believe that `b` is indeed a valid pointer to an instance of `B` - this is in fact all a C-style cast will ever do, as they involve no runtime behaviour. When you call `hi()` on it, the method works because:

- It doesn't access any instance variables belonging to `B` but not `A` (indeed, it doesn't access any instance variables at all)
- It's not virtual, so it doesn't need to be looked up in `b`'s vtable to be called

Therefore it works, but in almost all non-trivial cases such a malformed cast followed by a method call would result in a crash or memory corruption. And you can't rely on this kind of behaviour - *undefined* doesn't mean it has to be the same every time you run it, either. The compiler is perfectly within its rights with this code to insert a random number generator and, upon generating a 1, start up a complete copy of the original *Doom*. Keep that firmly in mind whenever anything involving undefined behaviour appears to work, because it might not work tomorrow and you need to treat it like that.